# Flutter ClipRRect can not clip the ripple effect of its child's InkWell widget

Tags: flutter

I wrapped an InkWell widget with a ClipRRect to add a rounded corner effect. The widget looks rounded after doing so, but when I long press it, the ripple effect breaks out the rounded corners and turn into the original square effect.

Here's a sample code. Long press 'Hello World' to see the ripple out of bounds. How should I solve this problem?

https://dartpad.dev/?id=7a4b8bf84ec51b5ed25c70f14d8c0e27

```dart
 return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4!.copyWith(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: ``InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000),
  // ...
);``

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need add to your `InkWell` too to apply ripple effect.

```dart
child: InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000),
  child: Text('Hello, World!'),
),
```

Comment: Yes it works! But I'm confused, I need to define the exact same borderRadius twice at the same time to implement the effect I want, which I think is strange.

Comment: me it's even worse as i am using a ClipPath @6v_